# Finding the minimum and maximum value of base where number of trailing zeroes is 24 of (100!)base 10

Tags: elementary-number-theory, number-systems

If $(100!)base10 is converted into base-b, the number of trailing zeroes is 24.

Find the maximum and minimum value of base b

In order to find the minimum and maximum value of b, in the solution they have found the highest power of 2 ,3, 4, 5 and 8 in 100!.

Also, the minimum value of b turned out to be $5$

The maximum value of b turned out to be $40$
How?

Comment: think about it this way for there to be a minimum 24 trailing 0's then 100! needs to be a multiple of at least $b^{24}$  what bases can this happen in ? edit: and if $b^{25}$ divides it then there's no longer just 24 trailing 0's

Comment: A little free tutoring: you tagged this "gmat-exam." But the GMAT does not test bases besides base 10. So there is no chance this question would appear on the GMAT. Of course, it's still an interesting question.

Comment: $100!$ contains $2^{97}$ and $5^{24}$ as factors in its decomposition in prime factor. So it's quite obvious that in base $5$ it has $24$ trailing zeroes, just like $10^{24}$ has $24$ trailing zeroes. Consider, however, that also $2^3 \times 5=40$ is a number which is a factor of $100!$. This means that you can write $100!=smthng\times 40^{24}$ which in base $40$ comes out to be written as a number with $24$ trailing zeros just like $stuff\times 10^{24}$ has $24$ trailing zeroes in decimal base. I hope I explained myself...

Answer (score 1):

The power with which $p$ occurs in $100!$ is $$v_p:=\left\lfloor \frac{100}p\right\rfloor +\left\lfloor \frac{100}{p^2}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{100}{p^3}\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor \frac{100}{p^4}\right\rfloor+\ldots$$
Thus if $b$ is a multiple of $p$, we need $v_p\ge 24$.
More generally, if $b$ is a multiple of $p^k$, we need $v_p\ge 24 k$.
Additionally, we know that for at least one prime, this inequality must be sharp (or else there would be *more* than $24$ zeroes), i.e., for some $p$, we have $v_p=24k$ where $p^k\| b$. The smallest valid choice is therefore $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=1$ (i.e., $b=5$), and the largest is $x=4$, $y=2$, $z=1$ (i.e., $b=720$).

Comment: Damn, this was tough to understand @HagenvonEitzen. Can you please explain it to me in a layman language

Comment: I'll show you what's meant:$$5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,$$$$55,60,65,70,75,80,85,90,95,100$$$$\to 1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2$$ this last part sums to 24 so the largest power of 5 that 100! divides by is $5^{24}$ the sum shows is counting the number divisible by different powers of p.

Comment: @SakuziMarkel In case you are unacquainted with the notation, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ denotes the largest integer $\le x$, and $p^k\|b$ means that $b$ is a multiple of $p^k$ but not of $p^{k+1}$.

Comment: You maybe need to add that you're talking about $2^x\cdot 3^y\cdot 5^z$ at some point.